# Peer to peer via Wi-Fi?

Tags: sockets, windows-phone-7, udp, tethering

Can I communicate from one WP7 device to another via UDP when one device enables tethering (becomes a wi-fi hotspot) and another one connects to him like to external Wi-fi hot-spot? Is this possible scenario? I just want to create p2p game.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To use UDP based socket connections on Windows Phone, all devices must already be connected to the same WiFi network. This means your scenario isn't possible.

See more on Windows Phone Sockets on MSDN at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh202874(v=vs.92).aspx